# How to get ReCaptcha to work using FormData() Ajax, Atachment, and ReCaptcha?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So have a Contact form that allows users to apply by uploading their resume and submit the form via ajax. So from what I have read I will have to use FormData() to pass along the attachment to the php file. This is causing me issues with my reCaptcha either not getting that data passed along or it being incorrect.

This is my code from my reCaptcha that works fine but it does not pass the attachment along.

```
$(function() {
var form = $("#ajax-contact");
var formMessages = $("#form-messages");
$(form).submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var name = $("#name").val();
var captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
var dataString = "name="+ name + "&captcha=" +captcha;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/assets/js/ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString
```

So next I converted this to work with my attachment and wrote this because when you pass along an attachment you have to use FormData() for the attachment to carry over.

```
$(function() {
var form = $("#ajax-resume");
var formMessages = $("#form-apply");
$(form).submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var dataString = new FormData(); 
dataString.append( 'name', $('#name').val());
dataString.append( 'captcha', grecaptcha.getResponse());
dataString.append( 'resume', $('input[name=resume]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/assets/js/ajaxsubmitresume.php",
data: dataString,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
dataType:'json'
```

From my understanding this should work exactly the same but my PHP always returns false on this statement.

```
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]) && !empty($_POST["captcha"])){
```

I cant seem to figure out what I am Missing I feel like its something simple but I have tried so many things its time to ask for help. If you need more info I will gladly provide it.